# Pattern-matching the nested union types

Tags: elm, algebraic-data-types

I'm modeling a count up/down timer. After the origin date is set, the timer displays how much time has passed since-, or remains till that origin date.

```
type OriginDefined
    = Up Date
    | Down Date


type Origin
    = OriginDefined
    | OriginUndefined


type Model
    = Tick OriginDefined
    | Edit Origin
```

Thus, the timer is ticking only when the origin date is defined. When the origin is edited though, it may or may not be previously defined.

Now I need a function to return the `defaultValue` for the date input, when we're in the `Edit` mode.

```
dateInputDefaultValue : Origin -> String
dateInputDefaultValue origin =
    case origin of
        OriginUndefined ->
            ""

        OriginDefined ->
            ...
```

Here I struggle to destructure the `origin` further as an `Up date` or `Down date`. In the 2nd branch of the `case` expression the compiler refuses to treat the `origin` as anything more specific than just an `Origin`.

Here's an Ellie https://ellie-app.com/3zKCcX87wa1/0

How should I deal with a model like that? Should I model in a different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your types compile, but you have two different definitions of `OriginDefined`: One is a type called `OriginDefined` which has two constructors, `Up` and `Down`. The other is a parameterless constructor on the type `Origin`.

My hunch is that you were trying to get the `OriginDefined` constructor on `Origin` to carry a value of type `OriginDefined`. In order to do that, you would have to define a parameter of type `OriginDefined` on the `OriginDefined` constructor:

```elm
type Origin
    = OriginDefined OriginDefined
    | OriginUndefined
```

Now you have a type that is isomorphic to Elm's `Maybe` type, so perhaps it would be less confusing and more idiomatic to remove the `OriginDefined` type and replace the definition of `Origin` with this:

```elm
type Origin
    = Up Date
    | Down Date
```

Now you can use `Maybe` in the places you were previously using defined/undefined nomenclature:

```elm
type Model
    = Tick (Maybe Origin)
    | Edit Origin
```

Pattern matching on `Maybe Origin` could look like this:

```elm
dateInputDefaultValue : Maybe Origin -> String
dateInputDefaultValue origin =
    case origin of
        Nothing ->
            ""

        Just (Up date) -> 
            "…"

        Just (Down date) -> 
            "…"
```